# Selecting adjacent siblings as separate groups between subheadings?

Tags: javascript, css

I need a way to identify all `<p>` tags between subheading tags `<h2>`as separated groups.

I can't use `h2 ~ p` as this selects all the `<p>` tags into a single selection.

I need to be able to stop the selection when another heading tag appears.

And the number of `<p>` tags will change so I doubt `::nth-child(x)` will help, although I could be wrong.

```
<section>
  <h2>Heading I want</h2>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <h2>Heading I don't want</h2>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
</section>
```

Is this possible?

### **Update** - Limitations:

Original structure can't be changed. The tool I'm using to export the text into data tables only has limited JS like commands that are as follows:

**$e.text** - gets the inner text or value

**$e.outerHTML** - get the outer html of the element

**$e.prop** - a function that behaves like jQuery prop function.

**$e.css** - a function that behaves like jQuery css function

**$e.parentProp** - a function that behaves like jQuery prop function.

**$e.parent** - get the parent element with all the same properties as $e/

Comment: Can you change the structure of the HTML or are you stuck with what you have?

Comment: Looking at your responses to the answers below, you might want to update your question and provide a bit more information about what you're trying to do and the limitations you have.

Comment: So you have some HTML and the tool you're using reads it and exports it somewhere? And you're trying to figure out how to only export the first group of paragraphs?

Comment: No, I've got 100's of old HTML pages that I want to export into a flexible format for a new design, so I need to be able to separate the various parts of the page according to their subheading into individual data cells so that when the text is re imported I've got control over how it gets inserted into the new layout. Exporting all the sub heading and text as one record and trying to fix after would require a lot more work, so I'd like to find a way of organising it properly on the way out.

Comment: Have you looked at tools like [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)? You could read pages using jsdom, pull out whatever data you need, and export to a format that your tools would understand better. And you could add whatever scripting you want, not limited to the functions your tools provide.

Answer (score 4):

If you are simply trying to add styling, you could apply styling to all of the `<p>` elements, and then remove that styling from the second group.

```css
h2:first-child ~ p {
  background: green;
}
h2:not(:first-child) ~ p {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Heading I want</h2>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <h2>Heading I don't want</h2>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
</section>
```

If you need to select them in JavaScript for something other than styling, you could use similar selectors to get all of them and then remove the ones in the second selection.

Comment: Not for styling, I'm trying to parse the data through an export tool, and want to be able to break up the various subsections into separate data fields that can then be re-imported into a new layout.

Comment: So you can get them using the same selector: `document.querySelectorAll("h2:not(:first-child) ~ p")`

Comment: Will you only ever have the two sections? The first group you want and the second group you don't. Or might there be three or more groups?

Comment: Number of groups can be anywhere between 6 or 7 or 50

Comment: mplungjan, didn't work for me, just selected all the tags as one set like normal.

Comment: If you can change the HTML, you could put each group of `<p>` elements into `<div>` blocks. Then just select the children of the div you want. But if you can't, I think you will want to use JavaScript to loop through siblings until you find the next `h2` or the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the groups, you could do something like this:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('section h2, section p')

let groups = []
let currentGroup = []

for(let element of elements) {
  if(element.tagName === 'H2') {
    if(currentGroup.length) {
      groups.push(currentGroup)
      currentGroup = []
    }
  }
  else {
    currentGroup.push(element)
  }
}

if(currentGroup.length) {
  groups.push(currentGroup)
}

console.log(groups)
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Heading I want</h2>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <h2>Heading I don't want</h2>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
</section>
```

And if you just want the first group:

```js
console.log(groups[0])
```

Or if you don't want to waste time getting the other groups:

```js
const getFirstGroup = (elements, groupStartTagName) => {
  let items = []
  let foundStart = false
  
  for(let element of elements) {
    if(element.tagName === groupStartTagName) {
      if(foundStart) {
        return items
      }
      else {
        foundStart = true
      }
    }
    else if(foundStart) {
      items.push(element)
    }
  }
  
  // if there's only one group, we'll loop through all the elements and get here
  return items
}

const group = getFirstGroup(document.querySelectorAll('section h2, section p'), 'H2')

console.log(group)
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Heading I want</h2>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <p>Some text I want</p>
  <h2>Heading I don't want</h2>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
  <p>Text I don't want</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you, the tool I'm using to export the data only has limited JS like function commands, nothing that would allow it to run whole snippets like that unfortunately. I wish it did.

Comment: The rules I can use are:

$e.text - gets the inner text or value
$e.outerHTML - get the outer html of the element
$e.prop - a function that behaves like jQuery prop function.
$e.css - a function that behaves like jQuery css function
$e.parentProp - a function that behaves like jQuery prop function.
$e.parent - get the parent element with all the same properties as $e/

Comment: What tool are you using? Do you have documentation?

Comment: Yeah it's called ParseHub https://help.parsehub.com/hc/en-us/articles/218224487-ParseHub-Expressions

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how limited you js functionality is, but if JQuery is available, you could perhaps do this.

```
$('section h2').each(function(){
    /*
      Here you could filter
      ex:
    */   
    if($(this).text() === 'Heading I want'){
        $(this).nextAll().each(function(){
            if($(this).is("p")){
                /*
                  Do something
                  ex:
                */
                alert($(this).text()); 
            } else {
                return false;
            };
        });
        return false;
    };
});
```